# Symfony configuration array adding new item

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, yaml

I have a problem with symfony 2.7.* configuration. I wanted to overwrite some parameter in configuration. Somewhere in my code I have

```
unsecured_controllers:
    - 'Bazinga\Bundle\JsTranslationBundle\Controller\Controller'
    - 'Gromar\Common\Infrastructure\WebBundle\Controller\ExceptionController'
    - 'Gromar\Common\UI\Menu\WebBundle\Controller\ContextMenuController'
    - 'Gromar\Common\UI\Menu\WebBundle\Controller\MainMenuController'
    - 'Gromar\Common\UI\Theme\WebBundle\Controller\ExceptionController'
    - 'Gromar\Common\UserManagement\WebBundle\Controller\AccountController'
    - 'Gromar\Common\UserManagement\WebBundle\Controller\UserOrganizationStructureDefaultController'
    - 'Gromar\Common\Message\WebBundle\Controller\MessageUnreadController'
    - 'Gromar\Common\Notification\WebBundle\Controller\NotificationToolbarController'
```

I wanted to add some more item to this array. Can I add it somehow instead of redefining whole array?

Comment: You want to edit the yaml file or dot it programmatically ?

Comment: I don't understand what are your needs. Your just have to add a line if you want